# Dynamicly call a variable from enum values

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I organize my strings with LocalizationsDelegate to manage locale language.

So to call a string, I write :

```
Languages.of(context).NAME_VARIABLE;
```

I have never seen what I'm trying to do and I'm not sure how to word it, so I'm gonna try to show what I want to achieve.

Let's say I have an enum class like this :

```
enum Numbers {
 one,
 two, 
 three,
}
```

I would like to dynamicly call strings (which I would have already added to my Languages files), something in this spirit :

```
  List<String> numbersStr = <String>[];
  for (String number in Numbers.values) {
  numbersStr.add(Languages.of(context).number);
}
```

Is there any way to do something like that, or do I have to manually link each value to its string?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it with translations but maybe its worth a try.
https://pub.dev/packages/enhanced_enum

Comment: If I understand correctly, this way looks like I would have to still manually link each value to its string. I'm planing to do that (by creating an extension to my enum class) if I don't find any other way.

Comment: I think I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you give another example?